# Invalid property name "minimum" etc. (M16)

Tags: qt, qml, slider

```js
       Slider
       {
           id: sldRed
           anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
           anchors.top: parent.top
           anchors.topMargin: 80
           width: 450
           minimum: 0
           maximum: 100
           value: 0
           step: 1
           backgroundEmpty: "lightgray"
           backgroundFull: "red"
           pressCircle: "red"
           onValueChanged:
           {
//               pwmRed.setPwmValue(value);
           }
       }
```

when I compile it gives the following errors:

```
Invalid property name "minimum". (M16)
Invalid property name "maximum". (M16)
Invalid property name "step". (M16)
Invalid property name "backgroundEmpty". (M16)
Invalid property name "pressCircle". (M16)
```

Included in the project is Slider.qml with all the properties in question

```js
import QtQuick 2.2

Item {
    id:slider
    height: heightSlider

    signal released(int value)
    signal pressed()

    property real value: 1
    onValueChanged: updatePos();
    property real minimum: 1
    property real maximum: 1
    property real step: 1
    property int xMax: width - handle.width
    onXMaxChanged: updatePos();
    onMinimumChanged: updatePos();

    property color backgroundEmpty: "lightgrey";
    property color backgroundFull: "#39F724";
    property real  backgroundopacity: 1;
    property real  backgroundopacityFull: 1;
    property color pressCircle: "#39F724"
    property color handleGrad1: "lightgray"
    property color handleGrad2: "gray"
    property real  heightSlider: 10
    property real  fullCircle: 30
    property real  circleWidth: 70
    property real  circleHeight: 70

......
......

......
}
```

I added Slider.qml with the properties:

```js
import QtQuick 2.2

Item {
    id:slider
    height: heightSlider

    signal released(int value)
    signal pressed()

    property real value: 1
    onValueChanged: updatePos();
    property real minimum: 1
    property real maximum: 1
    property real step: 1
    property int xMax: width - handle.width
    onXMaxChanged: updatePos();
    onMinimumChanged: updatePos();

    property color backgroundEmpty: "lightgrey";
    property color backgroundFull: "#39F724";
    property real  backgroundopacity: 1;
    property real  backgroundopacityFull: 1;
    property color pressCircle: "#39F724"
    property color handleGrad1: "lightgray"
    property color handleGrad2: "gray"
    property real  heightSlider: 10
    property real  fullCircle: 30
    property real  circleWidth: 70
    property real  circleHeight: 70

......
......

......
}
```

Comment: There is a QML item named [Slider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-slider.html), you should not confuse it with your custom element.

Comment: folibis is correct. Please do not name your component Slider.